# “energy saving” vs. “energy savings”

Tags: comparison, adjectives

Assume that A and B are two systems. For example A consumes 3unit and B consumes 4unit of the energy. Now we know to A saves 0.25% in energy consumption than B.I want to draw a diagram and want to type on the y axis. I would like to which of these is correct:

> 1. . . . the **energy saving ratio** of A **to** B . . .
> 2. . . . the **energy saving ratio** of A **than** B . . .
> 3. . . . the **energy savings ratio** of A **to** B . . .
> 4. . . . the **energy savings ratio** of A **than** B . . .
> 5. . . .. or?

Comment: Being unsure exactly what you mean, my best guess is that you probably want to say: *the energy savings of system A as compared to system B*.

Comment: Yes. I want to it. "the energy savings" s is required?

Comment: I would say _"the energy savings of A **over** B"._

Comment: @Finder, I'm not sure about the reason, but I understand that *savings* is the typical usage when being used like this.

Comment: Sorry,i want to draw a diagram and want to type on the y axis: "Energy saving ratio"     I would like to know it isn't correct?

Comment: @Finder Energy savings ratio, plural. "Energy saving ratio" would be a ratio which saves energy! :) ... and you will need to define the ratio at least in the text, if not on the diagram.

Comment: Finder, you really should provide much more context in future questions. When all you give us is a snippet – not even a full sentence! – it will be very hard to give an accurate answer. And clarifications should be made by editing your question, rather than by leaving a comment. No one, upon coming across your question for the first time, should have to read through an entire conversation below it just to figure out what you are asking about. More info available [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Answer (score 5):

Given a sufficiently convoluted context, I suppose it's at least remotely possible that some of your phrases could be correct. However, if we assume a normal, everyday context, I have to say *none* of your phrases are correct, because none of them make sense.

I think what you're trying to say is something like

> the energy savings of using A instead of B

You could shorten it to

> the energy savings of A vs. B

but in that case, it's not clear which system is more energy-efficient. (Using "over" instead of "vs.", as Tyler James Young suggested in the comments, would help clarify it.)

Note that the phrase is definitely "energy saving**s**", i.e. yes, you need that s on the end.

Answer (score 2):

The headline question asks about the difference between singular and plural *energy saving*, but I'll just say straight away that the rest of the sentence isn't well-constructed. It would be more "correct" to say something like..

> *the energy saving(s) [ratio] of A **compared** to B*

---

In OP's exact context, *energy saving(s)* is effectively a noun phrase being used adjectivally (i.e. - the *ratio* under consideration is calculated from the two different values of *energy saving(s)* for A and B).

I've put *[ratio]* in square brackets in my rephrasing because it's superfluous verbiage. I'd also point out that if A uses 3 units of energy where B uses 4, that means *A **saves 25%** relative to B* (not 0.25%).

---

Turning to the general case of singular/plural *energy savings*, you might like to look at [Pluralization of savings and costs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31095/) as asked previously on ELU. In OP's context I think either form is valid, and it's really stretching a point to suggest they actually *mean* different things.

But I do think there's a potential tiny difference based on the fact that plural *savings* is more associated with ***money put by for the future (i.e. - not spent)***. So you could say that using the plural places more emphasis on the *reduced monetary cost* for whoever pays the electricity bill, if they use A rather than B.

Conversely, if *saving* is given in the singular, this slightly places the emphasis on *the total amount of energy that's **not used**,* if people in general adopt A instead of B.

Thus there's (not much, but *some*) justification for saying that *savings* is more likely in an appeal to people's financial self-interest, as opposed to *saving* the planetary ecology (by us all using less energy).

Comment: +1, but I can't get behind singular "saving" as a noun.

Comment: @Tyler: Whyever not? Here are thousands of written instances of [*yields **a saving** of {some amount, percentage, or whatever}*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22yields+a+saving+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example. Obviously *that's* a "noun usage".

Comment: It just sounds wrong to me in this instance. I've never heard someone say “a saving of [x]”. Seeing it now, it strikes me as poetic [or out of date](http://goo.gl/s0VPNG).

Comment: @Tyler: I think your graph just reflects an increase over recent decades (particularly in the US) of *plural **savings** = money put by for the future (i.e. - not spent)*, as mentioned in my answer. But as I also pointed out, OP's usage is *effectively a noun phrase being used adjectivally*. That's the same usage as [*an energy **saving** design*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an+energy+saving+design%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which gets 1370 hits in Google Books, compared to just ***two*** for *an energy **savings** design*.

Comment: If it is the same usage as “energy saving design” then you have the problem StoneyB brought up, which is that the construction makes it look like a ratio is doing the saving of the energy (just like the design would in your example).

Comment: @Tyler:: ***I*** don't have a problem! I said straight off that *the sentence isn't well-constructed*, and in my example rephrasing I put the pluralising "s" in brackets. *And* I bracketed the word "ratio" itself *because it's superfluous verbiage.* You may wish to note that Google Books claims 982 instances of *energy **saving** ratio*, and 640 of *energy **savings** ratio*. In short, both are used, and we can all have our personal preferences, but I think it's a bit OTT to claim one is unambiguously "correct/grammatical" and the other is therefore "wrong".

Comment: I can appreciate that. I'm all for the more objective view you've presented (hence the +1). I just wanted to weigh in as someone to whom singular “saving” sounds prohibitively odd.