# What is the difference between"energy saving" and "energy savings"?

Tags: adjectives

When I read the papers, I sometimes see the phrases *energy saving* and *energy savings*. I don't understand how they are different. Compare these sentences:

> 1) However, the maximum **energy saving** obtained by the OTMR scheme depends on appropriate speed setting for the processing units, which in turn is determined by the system power characteristics.
>
> 2) As we discussed earlier, the processing speed for the ﬁrst two processing units in OTMR systems is critical in **energy savings**.
>
> 3) However, if it is possible to reduce the voltage at all by running slower, then there will be a net **energy savings** per cycle.

How are they different?

Comment: I'm pretty sure about #1 (the act of saving) and #3 (the amount of energy saved). However, I'm not sure about #2, it seems to be about the acts of energy saving. Perhaps there are many kinds of "energy saving" (similar to sense #1). --Hmm, reading it once again, and I'm not sure if #1 refers to the act or the amount of saving now.

Comment: Similar to http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14573/energy-saving-vs-energy-savings

Comment: @Steve: Duplicate, I'd say. Finder - since I don't really agree with the only answer on that earlier question, I'll post an answer *there* which will hopefully make things clearer for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a subtle difference, but one that's there if you think about how they're used in these examples.

'Energy saving' is a concept or a trait.  Example:

> This refridgerater is an 'energy saving' appliance; it only uses half as much power!

'Energy savings' is the literal savings of said appliance.  Example:

> The extra cost of a new refridgerater was easily covered by the 'energy savings' of having a more efficient appliance.